# Pandas read_excel returns unicode values (instead of floats) sometimes at the end of matrix rows

Tags: python, excel, pandas, unicode

I work with Python 2.7 on a Mac. I have [this data in Excel](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cbbjbj38sn9htn9/SO%20data.xlsx?dl=0) which I want to import in Python, possibly with Pandas. However, even if the importing goes smooth I have that some cells in the last column are actually imported as unicode characters (even if in excel they are truly floats..)

```
df = pd.read_excel('SO data', header = None, sheetname = None)
p = df['P'].values
```

and I get the strange character \uffde at the end of some cells closing some rows of the matrix...

Moreover, even if I fix it with something like float(unicode_cell[:-1]) I still have something strange, as if I try to check for nans with a function like isnan(p), I get an error like:

`TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''`

I really got stuck with this.
Any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you posted does indeed have 5 unicode characters in the last column. Once these are removed, `dtypes` are all `float`:

```
df = pd.read_excel('SO Data.xlsx'), header=None, sheetname='P')
print(df.info())

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 72 entries, 0 to 71
Columns: 3221 entries, 0 to 3220
dtypes: float64(3221)
memory usage: 1.8 MB
None
```